# Java : Power Massive Numbers

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class RSAEncryption {
public static void main(String[] args){
//STAGE ONE AND TWO
int p=61;
int q=53;
//STAGE THREE
Integer pq=p*q;
//STAGE FOUR
int pTotient=p-1;
int qTotient=q-1;
//STAGE FIVE
//  int finalTotient=pTotient*qTotient;
int finalTotient=780;
//STAGE SIX AND SEVEN
int e=0;
if((p>17)||(q>17)){
    e=17;
}else{
    e=7;
}
//STAGE EIGHT AND NINE
int d=0;
int count=0;
while ((e*d%finalTotient)!=1){
    d=d+1;
    count=count+1;
}
//STAGE TEN
int ed=e*d;
System.out.println("p = "+p);
System.out.println("q = "+q);
System.out.println("pq = "+pq);
System.out.println("final totient = "+finalTotient);
System.out.println("calculation of ed = "+ed);
System.out.println("d = "+d);
//ENCRYPTION
int message=65;
//PUBLIC KEY
int result00 = (int)Math.pow(message, e);
System.out.println(result00);
int testing00=result00%3233;
System.out.println(testing00);
BigInteger dd00=new BigInteger("65");
BigInteger test00=dd00.pow(17);
System.out.println("BigInteger Power Calc: "+test00);
int to100=test00.intValue();
int finalt=to100%3233;
System.out.println(to100);
```

From the code above you can see that I'm trying to make an RSA encryption algorithm in Java. The problem is that the power function that comes in built with Java "Math.pow()" is not precise enough, the final output "to100" should be equal to 2790. I'm not sure what I'm missing and have spent months on this.

I've also tried using BigInteger.pow() but to no avail. I'm not sure why the BigInteger.pow() method doesn't work.

I'm trying to get c :

c = 65^17 mod 3233 = 2790. As seen in the example over here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: The `BigInteger` class has a method to do [just this thing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)).

Comment: Example is [here](https://www.ideone.com/d4tvOS).

Answer (score 2):

This is all very easy if you use the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

example:

```
private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(61);
    BigInteger q = BigInteger.valueOf(53);
    BigInteger pq = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger finalTotient = p.subtract(ONE).multiply(q.subtract(ONE));
    BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(17);
    BigInteger d = e.modInverse(finalTotient);
    BigInteger message = BigInteger.valueOf(65);
    BigInteger encrypted = message.modPow(e, pq);
    BigInteger decrypted = encrypted.modPow(d, pq);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for a few reasons:

1. `Math.pow` uses `double`s, which only have 53 bits of precision, which isn't enough to hold the 103-bit number 6,599,743,590,836,592,050,933,837,890,625 (65<sup>17</sup>).
2. `BigInteger#intValue` produces an `int`, which only has 32 bits of precision, which is even worse suited for a 103-bit number.

You have two options, both of which involve staying within `BigInteger`s:

1. The slow way: perform `BigInteger`'s `mod` operation:

   ```java
   BigInteger n = new BigInteger("65");
   BigInteger p = n.pow(17);
   BigInteger m = new BigInteger("3233");
   BigInteger result = p.mod(m);
   ```
2. The fast way: perform `BigInteger`'s `modPow` operation:

   ```java
   BigInteger n = new BigInteger("65");
   BigInteger e = new BigInteger("17");
   BigInteger m = new BigInteger("3233");
   BigInteger result = n.modPow(e, m);
   ```

Comment: It's probably better to just use `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` instead of the constructor `BigInteger(String)`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I was trying to be more general, since RSA can be used with larger bit sizes than `long`s can hold (2048-bit keys are common these days).